# Binary classification with binary predictors

Tags: classification, binary-data, computational-statistics

I have a dataset with a binary response variable and 45 binary predictors. Which possible classification algorithms can I use? And how can i perform feature selection when most methods like best subset selection are built on minimizing RSS and dimension reduction methods like PCA finds M < p linear combinations of our original p predictors. I guess there are no linear combinations between X and Y when they are both binary?

I am currently looking at logistic regression, decision trees(RF and boosting) and SVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say decision tree/random forest might be a good option. Tree algorithms don't require feature scaling/normalizing and has in built feature selection.